# UIView not returning to proper position after animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have a simple `UITextField`, that when someone goes to edit it, and the  keyboard pops up, the view shifts up so that the user can see what they are entering. However, when I close the keyboard, the view is not returning to the original position! I am using a `CGPoint` property to capture its original position on `viewDidLoad` and then try and set it back to that when the keyboard is closed.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the original center point for shifting the view
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    self.originalCenter = self.view.center;
}

- (void)doneWithNumberPad {

    [locationRadius resignFirstResponder];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.center = self.originalCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.originalCenter.x, 150);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `viewDidLoad` is called, your view hierarchy has not yet been laid out for the current device's screen size or orientation.  It is too early to look at `self.view.center`.

Do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.originalCenter = self.view.center;
}
```

Note that if you support autorotation, even this won't work properly if the keyboard is visible when the autorotation happens.

Comment: Good thing I don't support auto rotation then!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require an absolute final center position, a sure-fire way to get this to work is to shift the views up by a fixed value defined by you when the keyboard shows and shift it down by that fixed value when the keyboard hides.

```
#define OFFSET 100

- (void)doneWithNumberPad {
    [locationRadius resignFirstResponder];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + OFFSET);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - OFFSET);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```